AWS Batch get all failed job name on specific Job Queue?
Is there a way to use AWS SDK, AWS Lambda or some python script to get all the job names that failed on specific job queue on AWS Batch? After extracting them, I would like to upload this to AWS S3 or RDS so that I can use it for Amazon QuickSight. I would like to also automatically run the script on a daily basis if that is also possible.
I have gone through AWS documents, but couldn't find any way that I can do this.

You can fetch failed AWS Batch jobs in specific queue using boto3 - see function get_failed_batch_job_names
I recommend running this script daily using AWS Lambda and EventBridge since you are already using AWS services.
You can follow this guide for a step-by-step setup: Creating a Scheduled Lambda Function on AWS.
Here are the key differences in your case:

You need to create IAM role that allows Lambda to write to s3 and to read from AWS Batch
Your cron expression should look like cron(0 12 * * ? *), which triggers the Lambda function daily at 12:00 UTC.

The script below is an example and can be further improved by:

get queue, bucket name from environment variables
add error handling
add logging
and more (I don’t have production experience with Lambda or Python, so there have to be additional areas for improvement)

import boto3
import json
from datetime import datetime


def get_failed_batch_job_names(job_queue):
    client = boto3.client('batch')
    response = client.list_jobs(jobQueue=job_queue, jobStatus='FAILED')

    return [job['jobName'] for job in response['jobSummaryList']]

def save_to_s3(failed_job_names, bucket, key):
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    body = json.dumps(failed_job_names)
    client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=body)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    job_queue = 'your_queue'
    bucket = 'your_bucket'
    
    failed_job_names = get_failed_batch_job_names(job_queue)

    date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    key = f'failed_jobs_in_{job_queue}_on_{date}.json'
    save_to_s3(failed_job_names, bucket, key)

    return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': f'Failed jobs saved to S3: {bucket}/{key}'
            }

